# Get data from multiple sites in Analytics

Tags: api, google-sheets, google-analytics

I need to change this code so that I have data from multiple sites in Analytics, ordered by date.

The code below works perfectly, but only for an Analytics account. I need to automate this, to get data from multiple sites in the same account.

```
function start(){


 ScriptApp.newTrigger("getGoogleAnalyticsData").timeBased().everyDays(1).create();


}

function onOpen() {
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

 ui.createMenu("Get external data")
 .addItem("Google Analytics", "getGoogleAnalyticsData")
 .addToUi();
}


function getGoogleAnalyticsData() {

  var date = new Date();

var startDate = "2020-01-01";
var endDate = "2020-12-31";

var tableId  = 'ga:201010452';
var metric = 'ga:totalPublisherRevenue';
var options = {
    'dimensions': 'ga:date',
    'sort': '-ga:date',
    'filters': 'ga:medium!==organic',
    'max-results': 425
};
var report = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, startDate, endDate, metric,options);

if (report.rows) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  var headers = report.columnHeaders.map(function(columnHeader) {
      return columnHeader.name;
  });
  sheet.appendRow(headers);

  sheet.getRange(2, 1, report.rows.length, headers.length)
        .setValues(report.rows);
} else {
    Logger.log('No rows returned.');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Analytics Management API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3) to get profile list from your account and adapt the code to cycle and query the views of interest.